# Deciding to take a break

Tags: discussion

I've decided to take a break from Stack Exchange. The reasons are probably pretty obvious, but the details can be found on [this Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334024/a-very-recent-post-asking-people-to-go-on-strike-was-just-deleted) about another Meta post I made which was deleted by staff. Knowing myself, I'm sure I'll be lurking and will come back in not too long, but for the time being I don't plan to contribute in any meaningful way.

Comment: I am also joining and "retiring in restricted mode" until this situation is sorted out.

Comment: Your post tried to organize a strike? Were you surprised that it was deleted?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, not entirely, and I can understand the reason behind removing it. I'm not taking a break because the post was deleted - the deleted post explains why I'm taking a break.

Comment: aww man, I usually like your answers... come join me sipping whiskey in the shade for a while

Comment: Thanks @Kilisi, that means a lot coming from you! And believe me, I've got plenty of whiskey stocked up at home :)

Answer (score 21):

I don't have enough rep to really warrant my own meta-question, so I'll just piggy-back onto yours.

I am also going to take a break.

Comment: 17.9 k is a lot of rep.... enjoy your break

Comment: Awwwww :( I like your answers a lot... I was 3 days away and still trying to understand the whole chain of events

Comment: Thank you @JulianaKarasawaSouza That means a lot to me.

Comment: You still matter, Sir

Answer (score 7):

Can't say I blame you.

You contribute quite a bit, and are a valued member of the community, I wish you well